# NDB-like async operations in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-asyncio

When programming on App Engine and using NDB to deal with Google's Datastore, [the ndb package](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/async) exposes async methods whose API is very clear and usage is easy:

```
future = my_key.get_async()
# do some work
entity = future.get_result()
```

It appears that with asyncio, any bare Python program can make use of the same kind of machinery and the same capabilities for all sorts of purposes. However, the asyncio API is well less friendly, mostly because one needs to explicitly manage an event loop, and also because everything in the program must be thought in the async way. This contrasts with the NDB API where some async things can be plugged here and there without disturbing the rest of the program, and yet the async processes behave as wished.

Before I dig into the source code of the package I just would like to know whether there were some remarkable pointers about this.

Comment: I haven't looked at the implementation, but `future.get_result()` looks like it behaves a lot like `thread.join()`, so maybe it's implemented using the `threading` module.

Answer (score 1):

NDB indeed uses an event loop, but a highly customized one, tailored for the GAE (standard) environment. Not necessarily based on the `threading` module (`threading.local` is used, but only if the app is configured as thread-safe and anyways there is one event loop per thread/request). I guess because of its very specific usage it could be well and conveniently hidden behind the higher level APIs.

You can find it in [`appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop.py`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/eventloop):

```
"""An event loop.

This event loop should handle both asynchronous App Engine RPC objects
(specifically urlfetch, memcache and datastore RPC objects) and arbitrary
callback functions with an optional time delay.

Normally, event loops are singleton objects, though there is no
enforcement of this requirement.

The API here is inspired by Monocle.
"""
```

By contrast providing a managed general-purpose event loop which would work well in any environment is not an easy task, which is, I suspect, why asyncio leaves it at the programmer's discretion - for proper tailoring according to the application environment and implementation.